# How can I include kotlin-reflect in the classpath of the Bazel compiler?

Tags: kotlin, bazel, annotation-processing

I'm trying to get [moshi-kotlin-codegen](https://github.com/square/moshi#codegen) to run on some Kotlin code via Bazel. After a lot of trial and error, I managed to get the plugin to run, but it's failing due to not having kotlin-reflect on the classpath. This is needed by [kotlinpoet](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet), which is used by Moshi, so it should be transitively included, AFAICT. However, even explicitly stating the dependency in the BUILD.bazel file for moshi-kotlin-codegen doesn't make it work, so I can only assume it gets filtered out somewhere.

The WORKSPACE file:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "rules_jvm_external",
    sha256 = "62133c125bf4109dfd9d2af64830208356ce4ef8b165a6ef15bbff7460b35c3a",
    strip_prefix = "rules_jvm_external-3.0",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/archive/3.0.zip",
)

load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "com.github.ajalt:clikt:2.6.0",
        "org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.7.0.202003090808-r",
        "io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.7.8",
        "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3",
        "com.github.scribejava:scribejava-core:6.9.0",
        "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.2",
        "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.2",
        "org.kohsuke:github-api:1.108",
        "com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:2.8.2",
        "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1",

        "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.0",
        "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.6.0",
        "com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1",
    ],
    fetch_sources = True,
    repositories = [
        "https://maven.google.com",
        "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
        "https://jcenter.bintray.com/",
    ],
    strict_visibility = True,
)

rules_kotlin_version = "legacy-1.4.0-rc3"
rules_kotlin_sha = "da0e6e1543fcc79e93d4d93c3333378f3bd5d29e82c1bc2518de0dbe048e6598"

http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_kotlin",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin/releases/download/%s/rules_kotlin_release.tgz" % rules_kotlin_version],
    sha256 = rules_kotlin_sha,
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:kotlin.bzl", "kotlin_repositories", "kt_register_toolchains")

kotlin_repositories()

kt_register_toolchains()
```

The BUILD.bazel for moshi-kotlin-codegen:

```
java_plugin(
    name = "moshi_kotlin_codegen_plugin",
    processor_class = "com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.codegen.JsonClassCodegenProcessor",
    deps = [
      "@maven//:com_squareup_moshi_moshi_kotlin_codegen",
    ],
    generates_api = True,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

(I also tried adding a `java_library` and depending on that, no luck.)

The final BUILD file that tries to include it:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:kotlin.bzl", "kt_jvm_binary")

kt_jvm_binary(
    name = "myproject",
    srcs = glob([
          "**/*.kt",
    ]),
    main_class = "my.project.MainKt",
    plugins = [
            "//third_party/moshi_kotlin_codegen:moshi_kotlin_codegen_plugin",
    ],
    deps = [
        "@maven//:ch_qos_logback_logback_classic",
        "@maven//:com_github_ajalt_clikt",
        "@maven//:com_github_ben_manes_caffeine_caffeine",
        "@maven//:com_github_scribejava_scribejava_core",
        "@maven//:com_squareup_moshi_moshi",
        "@maven//:io_github_microutils_kotlin_logging",
        "@maven//:org_eclipse_jgit_org_eclipse_jgit",
        "@maven//:org_kohsuke_github_api",
        "@maven//:javax_xml_bind_jaxb_api",
    ],
)
```

The exception during the compilation:

```
Caused by: kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath
    at kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference.error(ClassReference.kt:79)
    at kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference.getQualifiedName(ClassReference.kt:15)
    at com.squareup.kotlinpoet.ClassNames.get(ClassName.kt:49)
    at com.squareup.moshi.kotlinpoet.classinspector.elements.ElementsClassInspector.<clinit>(ElementsClassInspector.kt:493)
    at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.codegen.JsonClassCodegenProcessor.process(JsonClassCodegenProcessor.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:147)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:980)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: Having spent some more time researching this, I'm thinking it's a bug: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin/issues/342

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this was indeed a bug. A fix is https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin/pull/354.